# Golang: Slicing and populating byte arrays

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I'm trying to write a packet protocol using golang.  As the protocol will have a fixed length, it seems like a good starting point to allocate the exact amount of memory. E.g.

```
packet := make([]byte, 1024)
```

What I don't understand is how to then populate specific elements of that packet.  I want to say something like:-

```
slice = pointer(packet[512])
slice = []byte("abcdef")
```

The result being that packet[512:518] == []byte("abcdef").  The docs I've read on Arrays and Slices show how to modify a single byte in a slice but not a contiguous sequence of bytes.  Is there a method to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can’t do this. The closest way I can tell is use copy. check: http://play.golang.org/p/PtGJuVgEjc

Comment: and you don't even need the temporary slice: `copy(slice[512:], "abcde")`

Comment: That actually does exactly what I want. Thanks!