# How to change some bytes in a byte[] at a specific index in GO programming?

Tags: go, byte

I have a []byte that which is essentially a string, in this array I have found something I want to change using index:

```
content []byte
key []byte
newKey []byte
i = bytes.Index(content, key)
```

So I have found key in content (at index I), now I want to replace key with newKey but I can't seem to find a way to add it in I was trying the obvious thing that wouldn't work :)

```
content[i] = newKey
```

Is there some function that allows me to replace "key" with "newKey" within content []byte?

Thanks,

Comment: use copy check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806867/golang-slicing-and-populating-byte-arrays  but need len(newKey)==len(key)

Comment: if the []byte is essentially a string why not use the strings package?  `content = []byte(strings.Replace(string(content), string(key),string( newKey)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the article "[Go Slices: usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)", you can use `copy` in order to create a slice with the right content:

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/4Gh-OEnz9g)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    slice := make([]byte, 10)
    copy(slice[2:], "a")
    copy(slice[3:], "b")
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", slice)
}
```

Output:

```
[0 0 97 98 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

---

In your case, if `len(key) == len(newJey)`:

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/xmMdwJJksz)

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "bytes"

func main() {
    content := make([]byte, 10)
    copy(content[2:], "abcd")
    key := []byte("bc")
    newKey := []byte("xy")
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", content, key)

    i := bytes.Index(content, key)
    copy(content[i:], newKey)
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", content, newKey)
}
```

Output:

```
[0 0 97 98 99 100 0 0 0 0] [98 99]
[0 0 97 120 121 100 0 0 0 0] [120 121]
```